# Is it possible to set the upload location to a different server?

Tags: content, uploads, shared-hosting

Our university has given our student society a 1GB portion of storage to be used for our website. We're low on their bandwidth priority however so it did not work speedily with Wordpress.

I managed to purchase ourselves our own domain name, including hosting at a very cheap price (£14 per annum total). The only problem (not a problem yet, but in the future it might be) is that it comes with only 250mb of storage.

Is there a way to set wordpress uploads over a certain size (500kb for example) to be automatically uploaded to our university-provided hosting instead? I'd quite like the majority of pictures to load fast, but with massive uploads not hogging our limited storage capacity.

I should emphasise that I want my website users to be able to upload in the conventional way, but for their files above a certain size to be automatically stored in another storage location, instead of the default one.

Answer (score -1):

Sign up for a free hosting and store your files there. There are no problems with linking :) Sign up for a free hosting and store your files there. There are no problems with linking :)

The simplest solution.

Comment: **What is this?** I mean, why the cloned line? Take a look here: [How do I write a good answer to a question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656/185667).

Comment: Agreed with @brasofilo. ***What is this?***

Comment: I have no problem storing the files manually and linking to them.

Maybe I should emphasise that I want my website users to be able to upload in the conventional way, but for their files above a certain size to be automatically stored in another storage location.